# Hide and Show field set

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, show

i want to hide/show field set with a toggle. But it won't work! Can someone please help me? I don't know what's wrong in my code and i want to toggle it. The last two field sets have to hide and have to be enabled by clicking on the radio buttons.

```
    <section>
        <h1>Aanmelden</h1>
          <p>Bent u geïnteresseerd in samenwerken met CMD Amsterdam? Dat kan!Tijdens de opleiding werken studenten aan projecten voor echte opdrachtgevers.Ook lopen de studenten stage, in het tweede en afstudeerjaar.

          <em>CMD Amsterdam zoekt altijd naar positieve verbindingen met de creatieve stad Amsterdam.</em>

          Voor het aanmelden van stageplekken of projecten kunt u onderstaand formulier invullen Wij nemen zo nodig contact met u op nadat het formulier is verstuurd. Voor vragen of opmerkingen kunt u <a href="contact.html">contact</a> met ons op.
          </p>
    </section>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Contactgegevens</legend>
            <label for="Naam">Naam</label>
            <input id="Naam" type="text" required/>
            <label for="Bedrijf">Bedrijf</label>
            <input id="Bedrijf" type="text" required/>
            <label for="Adres">Adres</label>
            <input id="Adres" type="text" required/>
            <label for="Postcode">Postcode</label>
            <input id="Postcode" type="text" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}" required/>
            <label for="Plaats">Plaats</label>
            <input id="Plaats" type="text" required/>
            <label for="Telefoon">Telefoon</label>
            <input id="Telefoon" type="text" required/>
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            <input id="Email" type="text" required/>

            Ik wil mijn aanmelden:
            <input id="Project" type="radio" required/>
            <label for="Project">Voor een project</label>
            <input id="Stage" type="radio" required/>
            <label for="Stage">Als stagebedrijf</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset >
            <legend>Project</legend>
            <label for="Titel">Titel</label>
            <input id="Titel" type="text"/>
            <label for="Opdrachtomschrijving">Opdrachtomschrijving</label>
            <input id="Opdrachtomschrijving" type="text"/>
            <label for="Doelgroepomschrijving">Doelgroepomschrijving</label>
            <input id="Doelgroepomschrijving" type="text"/>
            <label for="Doelstelling">Doelstelling / intentie van het project</label>
            <input id="Doelstelling" type="text"/>
            <label for="Looptijd">Looptijd (maximaal 24 maanden)</label>
            <input id="Looptijd" type="range" min="1" max="24"/>
            <label for="Deadline">Deadline</label>
            <input id="Deadline" type="date"/>
            Geschikt voor
            <input id="eerstejaars" type="radio"/>
            <label for="eerstejaars">Eerstejaars studenten</label>
            <input id="tweedejaars" type="radio"/>
            <label for="tweedejaars">Tweedejaars studenten</label>
            <input id="derdejaars" type="radio"/>
            <label for="derdejaars">Derdejaars studenten</label>
            <input id="afstudeer" type="radio"/>
            <label for="afstudeer">Afstudeer studenten</label>
            <input id="onbekend" type="radio"/>
            <label for="onbekend">Onbekend</label>
            Opmerkingen?
            <input id="opmerkingen" type="text"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Stage</legend>
            Geschikt voor:
            <input id="tweedestage" type="radio"/>
            <label for="tweedestage">Tweedejaars studenten</label>
            <input id="afstudeerders" type="radio"/>
            <label for="afstudeerders">Afstudeer studenten</label>
            <input id="nietbekend" type="radio"/>
            <label for="nietbekend">Onbekend</label>

            Hoe lang is de stage?
            <input id="tien" type="radio"/>
            <label for="tien">Tien weken</label>

            <input id="twintig" type="radio"/>
            <label for="twintig">Twintig weken</label>
            <input id="unknown" type="radio"/>
            <label for="unknown">Onbekend</label>
            <label for="begindatum">Begindatum</label>
            <input id="begindatum" type="date"/>
            <label for="werkzaamheden">Beschrijving werkzaamheden</label>
            <input id="werkzaamheden" type="text"/>
            Beschrijving stagebedrijf
            <label for="bedrijfsnaam">Bedrijfsnaam</label>
            <input id="bedrijfsnaam" type="text" required/>
            <label for="address">Adres</label>
            <input id="address" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
            <label for="zip">Postcode</label>
            <input id="zip" type="text" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}
             "/>
            <label for="woonplaats">Plaats</label>
            <input id="woonplaats" type="text" required/>
            <label for="sector">Sector</label>
            <input id="sector" type="text"/>
            <label for="core">Core Business</label>
            <input id="core" type="text"/>
            Opmerkingen?
            <input id="opmerking" type="text"/>
        </fieldset>
        <input id="verzenden" type="submit"/>
 </form>


</body>



body{
   background: #efefef;
  min-height: 100%;
  font: 100%/1.5 helvetica, arial;
   } 

label {
display: block;
margin: 0 0 1em;
}
label > input {
display: block;
}

input[type="radio"] + label{
   display: inline;
}

 input, button {
  font: inherit;
}
fieldset{
   background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff, lime);
 }

  .is-invisible{
   display: none;
}
  .is-visible {
    display: block;
  }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
   var fieldset = document.querySelector('fieldset:nth-of-type(2,3)');

  fieldset.classlist.add('hidefieldset');

  document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]').onclick = function() {
  fieldset.classList.add('showfieldset');
}

  document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:last-of-type').onclick = function() {
fieldset.classlist.remove('showfieldset');
}
```

Thanks for helping xx

Comment: It looks like you are referencing classes that don't actually exist. You are adding the CSS classes 'hidefieldset' and 'showfieldset' and I don't see those in your code. maybe try using the is-invisible and is-visible classes and see if those work instead

Comment: thanks but even when i change that, it won't work!

Comment: Another thing to point out. 'querySelector' only selects the first element that matches the criteria you laid out. Either separate it into two variables, or look up querySelectorAll (please note that querySelectorAll returns an array that you will need to loop through). If you want to be able to alter DOM elements in bulk, maybe consider using jQuery instead.

Comment: the problem is: i can't use jquery for this project. that's why i use nth

Comment: Then, as I said in my prior comment...either create two separate vars, one to represent each fieldset, or use querySelectorAll to generate an array of elements that you can loop through.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try but i don't think i'm able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is:

```
<legend class="legend">
    <div style="display:none;">
        ... content ...
    </div>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$(".legend").click(function(e) { $(this).next("div").toggle(); });
```

This will keep the Legend visible and clickable.
Show to the user that it is clickable with some CSS:

```
.legend { cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach your problem with jQuery's toggle method. First, I created a button with a class of toggle. So every time when a user clicks on the button, the content of the fieldset element will show and hide upon each click event. 
But since buttons have default actions to actually submit something the same way anchored links do,

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("fieldset").toggle();
    })
})
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0mmaqoL/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use jQuery set id on that inputs

```
        <input id="Project" type="radio" name="ps" required/>
        <label for="Project">Voor een project</label>
        <input id="Stage" type="radio" name="ps" required/>
        <label for="Stage">Als stagebedrijf</label>
```

and use script

```
function $(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var fieldset = [ $('fProject'), $('fStage') ];

fieldset[0].style.display = 'none';
fieldset[1].style.display = 'none';

$('Project').onclick = function() {
    fieldset[0].style.display = 'block';
    fieldset[1].style.display = 'none';
};

$('Stage').onclick = function() {
    fieldset[1].style.display = 'block';
    fieldset[0].style.display = 'none';
};
```